# I am getting a weird error with an OSError ID: WinError 10038

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error

I am trying to code a server with the following code. It is threaded and all I need help with is this error.

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function threaded_client at 0x0000000003302158>
line 28, in threaded_client
data = conn.recv(2048)
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

This error I cannot solve and have tried to solve. I would really like to know how to fix it.

```
import socket
import sys

from _thread import *
import time

host = ''
port = 5555
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.bind((host,port))
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))    


s.listen(5)

print("Waiting for a Connection...")
def threaded_client(conn):

    conn.send(str.encode("Welcome, please write to the server.\r\n"))
    userinput = ""

    while True:
        data = conn.recv(2048)
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        if not data:
            break
        #data = data.decode('utf-8')
        #Gather up the Input
        if data == '\r\n':
            userinput += data
        #Do something with it
        else:
            reply = 'Server output: ' + userinput
            conn.sendall(str.encode(reply))
            userinput = ""

            conn.close()
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("connected to: " +addr[0] + ': ' + str(addr[1]))
    start_new_thread(threaded_client, (conn,))
```

Now I am having an issue with how the server interacts with the client. Image of my CMD window open bellow. Please provide code to fix.
For windows 8, please.
[image: Image Link]

Comment: Check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210178/python-socket-programming-oserror-winerror-10038-an-operation-was-attempted-o?bcsi_scan_94a977aee9df674a=3DSJp4a+bDXk1nRlDXbwkv84AccIAAAA76R6ZQ==

Comment: Ill be on in the morning - its getting late so dont expect a response right away!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this part.

```
else:
     reply = 'Server output: ' + userinput
     conn.sendall(str.encode(reply))
     userinput = ""
     conn.close() #<--- here you are closing the connection
```

This should be outside the loop. Something like this.

```
while True:
        data = conn.recv(2048)
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        if not data:
            break
        #data = data.decode('utf-8')
        #Gather up the Input
        if data == '\r\n':
            userinput += data
        #Do something with it
        else:
            reply = 'Server output: ' + userinput
            conn.sendall(str.encode(reply))
            userinput = ""

conn.close() #<--- Notice the indent
```

Comment: Thanks Prajwal - Will test shortly

Comment: Sorry to bother you again - but I have an issue where after each keystroke it prints out the "Server Output" message and I want it after the user presses enter. Do you have any idea how?

Comment: sorry to bother you - but I need your help with another part of the question.<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41739306/client-to-client-chats-via-a-server-python-3-any-module-like-socket-ipaddress-a>