# Send IP notification with Python

Tags: python, tcp, notifications

I want to be able to send IP notifications through TCP to a server with a specific string.
The idea behind the project is this: I have a camera that saves a picture on event (like movement) in a folder and I have a watchdog sort of program that watches that directory for changes i.e new files. I need this script to send the path to the picture through local network to the server that has a `listener` on that port `34000`.

How can I achieve this?

The code I have right now is this (in the example I send 10 times the same message):

```
import byte
import socket

host = 'ip.of.the.host'
port = 34000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))
for i in range(10):
   message = bytes('some message', 'utf-8')
   s.send(message)
s.close()
```

Here I have the error :

```
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

Comment: That is an error that retuns when the sockets are closed, verify that the server is listening correctly on that port and that IP

Comment: You close the socket directly after the first send. This means the next send in the loop will be called on a closed socket. You should close the socket only after you are done sending everything.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks that removed the error. enriqueojedalara yes I've checket it is open and listenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is raised because the socket is not open, it's similar to this [python socket programming OSError: [WinError 10038] an operation was attempted on something that is not a socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210178/python-socket-programming-oserror-winerror-10038-an-operation-was-attempted-o.)